# How to programmatically get schema from confluent schema registry in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

As of now i am doing something like this reading avsc file to get schema

```
value_schema = avro.load('client.avsc')
```

can i do something to get schema from confluent schema registry using topic-name?

i found one way but didn't figure out how to use it.

https://github.com/marcosschroh/python-schema-registry-client

Comment: All you need is an HTTP client to access the REST API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this it worked for me

```
     import requests
     import os

     SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL = os.getenv('SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL');
     print("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: ", SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL)
     URL = SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL + '/subjects/' + topic + '/versions/latest/schema'
     r = requests.get(url=URL)
     schema = r.json()


     print("Schema From Schema Registry ==========================>>")
     print("Schema: ", schema)
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

**Using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python)**

```
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient

sr = CachedSchemaRegistryClient({
    'url': 'http://localhost:8081',
    'ssl.certificate.location': '/path/to/cert',  # optional
    'ssl.key.location': '/path/to/key'  # optional
})

value_schema = sr.get_latest_schema("orders-value")[1]
key_schema= sr.get_latest_schema("orders-key")[1]
```

---

**Using [`SchemaRegistryClient`](https://marcosschroh.github.io/python-schema-registry-client/client/)**

*Getting schema by subject name*

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient


sr = SchemaRegistryClient('localhost:8081')
my_schema = sr.get_schema(subject='mySubject', version='latest')
```

*Getting schema by ID*

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient


sr = SchemaRegistryClient('localhost:8081')
my_schema = sr.get_by_id(schema_id=1)
```

Comment: Precisely. Just a note to add that typically the subject for a topic will be <topic>-key or <topic>-value depending on which bit of the message you are reading. Also, you may instead (the confluent serde, as I understand it) encode the actual schema id into the serialised message somehow and you access the schema by that rather than subject and version.

Comment: @wobr Actually you can omit `version`. In that case you will get the latest subject schema.

Comment: Latest is not always what you want.

Comment: @wobr the confluent_kafka Python library handles the "somehow" of encoding the message with the ID

Comment: @wobr - So you mean to say for each record, get the schema from schema registry? Will it not be slow down the performance ?

Comment: I imagine it's cached

Answer (score 4):

you can use `get_latest_version` function to get schema information

```html
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient

sr = SchemaRegistryClient({"url": 'http://localhost:8081'})
subjects = sr.get_subjects()
for subject in subjects:
    schema = sr.get_latest_version(subject)
    print(schema.version)
    print(schema.schema_id)
    print(schema.schema.schema_str)
```